# Passing stream from test case to method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, stream, moq

I am writing test cases for an API.

In the API, I am getting the memory stream in the body of HttpRequest. In the below snippet, `req` is an instance of `HttpRequest`

```
string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
```

So, while mocking I have this code:

```
Data data = new Data()
{
    width = 400,
    height = 600,
    text = "text",
    barcodeformat = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128.ToString()
};

byte[] inputData = null;
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bf.Serialize(ms, data);
    inputData = ms.ToArray();
}
var mockHttp = new Mock<HttpRequest>();
mockHttp.Setup(x => x.Body).Returns(new MemoryStream(inputData));
```

But in the API code, I am getting the value in `data` as empty string. 
 Please help me to understand where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JsonConvert` expects json, but you don't have json here.